# CA2202 Объект можно удалять более одного раза в методе

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Студия предложила следующее:

> Предупреждение    CA2202  Объект "'sw'" можно удалять более одного раза в
>   методе  Чтобы избежать исключения System.ObjectDisposedException,
>   следует вызывать метод "Dispose" для объекта только один раз.

на такой вот код:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SListData));
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false),
        Indent = true,
        NewLineOnAttributes = true,
    })
    )
    {
        s.Serialize(xw, __data);
        // строка о чем речь ниже
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

как она пришла к такому выводу? или я чего не замечаю?

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится

Comment: Возможно, студия намекает вам, что sw будет и так прибита созданным XmlWriter и бить её второй раз не понадобится. Но это не точно :)

Comment: @tym32167, вроде, никогда с этими декораторами для потоков проблем не было

Comment: @АндрейNOP да я просто пальцем ткнул в небо, больше вызовов dispose тут по сути нет же

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится, а вообще вот https://stackoverflow.com/a/3839419/5574962

Comment: В описании [CA2202](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2202-do-not-dispose-objects-multiple-times?view=vs-2017#example) сказано: "Nested using statements can cause violations of the CA2202 warning". Там описано, как этого избежать. Но в данном конкретном случае на это можно забить, т. к. `Dispose` у "родных" дотнетных классов реализован правильно.

Comment: Перевод ошибки на русский, конечно, печалит: "можно удалять". :(

Comment: Ну не знают они в оборотах речи великий и могучий .. :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP В меню `Сборка` выбрать `Анализ кода`, если не воспроизводиться. Ошибка на 2017 с последним вчерашним апдейтом.

Comment: @NewView это анализ кода на предмет потенциальных проблем. Он часто выдает false positive. Не все выдаваемые предупреждения на самом деле означают, что проблема есть. В вашем случае - да, если у XmlWriter выставить CloseOutput = true - будет двойной Dispose. Если не выставить - не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, про `CloseOutput = true` учту, никогда не использовал.